# Difference on writing method with beginTransaction() and commit() it or without writing beginTransaction() and without commit() it

Tags: hibernate

What is the difference between these two snippet of code ,basically i have some confusion on these two snippet of code in first code i am performing action `create` by beginning a transaction and then committing it ,and in second snippet i am not writting the `session.beginTransaction() and tx.commit()` which is the best approach and why?

One more question is `select query`  also considered as transaction? or transaction is series of more than one action like create update and delete in one unit of work ?

```
public boolean createProject(EmployeeProject employeeProject) {
        Transaction tx = null;
        boolean flag = false;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(employeeProject);
            tx.commit();
            flag = true;
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null)
                tx.rollback();

        }
        return flag;
    }
```

second approach

```
public boolean createProject(EmployeeProject employeeProject) {
        boolean flag ;
        try {
            session.save(employeeProject);
            flag = true;
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            flag=false;

        }
        return flag;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the definition:

> A transaction is associated with a Session and is usually instantiated
>   by a call to Session.beginTransaction(). A single session might span
>   multiple transactions since the notion of a session (a conversation
>   between the application and the datastore) is of coarser granularity
>   than the notion of a transaction. However, it is intended that there
>   be at most one uncommitted Transaction associated with a particular
>   Session at any time.

Since you're doing a WRITE operation (insert-update-delete), You won't be able to persist the object in db with the 2nd approach. To persist an object in database you have to begin a Transaction & commit it.

2nd approach is better only for READ operations (e.g. SELECT queries).

Comment: so i dont need session.beginTransaction in READ but its definetly needed in WRITE am i correct